# Grab Random Line from .txt then delet the line

Tags: php

So here is basically what i want to do, say var.txt is  = :

```
bar
foo
smooth
green
```

then say i run a code like this in php to grab a random line:

```
$mineloc = file("var.txt");
$mineacc = $mineloc[array_rand($mineloc)];
```

what would i do then to remove the line that shows up in `$mineacc` from var.txt which will result in var.txt being this if the word `smooth` was generated:

```
bar
foo
green
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to delete a single line in a txt file with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48490252/how-to-delete-a-single-line-in-a-txt-file-with-php)

Comment: Naive approach: read every line from file, then overwrite the file with the lines you read, minus the one that you picked. See the possible duplicate question for more details.

Answer (score 2):

I hope this will solve your problem....

```
$content = file_get_contents('var.txt');
$contentArray = explode('
',$content);

unset($contentArray[rand(0, count($contentArray))]);

file_put_contents('var.txt', implode('
',array_values($contentArray)));
```

Comment: but sir wouldnt this put the line back inside the file? i want it removed completly

Comment: have you executed it ?

Comment: doesnt work, when i try to echo out $contentArray it just echos array and then when i check var.txt it is empty.

Comment: idk then do you have any other method that might work with the line like

Comment: $mineacc = $mineloc[array_rand($mineloc)];